# Individualized schedules for event attendees

Tags: algorithm

I'm interested in building software that will take a list of attendees, each tagged according to their experience level, interests, etc., and a list of classes, each tagged with difficulty level, type of content, etc. and will produce individualized schedules for each attendee.

Clearly, this is a common problem and I'm guessing there are some standard algorithms for handling it. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Specifically, what is this operation called and, if there is a standard algorithm, what is it called?

Thanks!

Comment: My colleague pointed me to this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257826/efficient-scheduling-of-university-courses/13258093#13258093) which covers the topic pretty well. Still interested to know if there are any open source libraries.

Comment: Asking for recommendations (points #2 and #3) are off topic, as per the [help/on-topic]. I suggest you edit these out of your question, assuming that would leave you with a question worth asking, given the linked post.

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be a bit broad, but your comment already pointed in the direction of using [integer programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) to solve this scheduling problem. So to the point of open source libraries for the job:

- GNU MathProg probably is the easiest way to formulate and solve (using GLPK) such problems. You can try out [some examples directly in the browser](https://www3.nd.edu/~jeff/mathprog/mathprog.html) (thanks to a port of GLPK and Mathprog to Javascript). Maybe have a look at some of the scheduling examples...
- Then there are plenty of libraries that offer similar functionality in the programming language of your choice. In Python, [Pyomo](https://software.sandia.gov/trac/coopr/wiki/Pyomo) is one of the available options.

This leaves you with the problem to design an objective function that serves as the quality measure to compare different schedule variants.